# Is it possible to totally hide folded lines?

Tags: folding

As title , folded lines usually displays as one line , with the content configurable; is it possible to hide folded lines totally?

And of course, I’d hope there’s still a way to unfold them, for example, by press space twice at the line above.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are asking is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you partway there. The only thing left (I think) is to configure your syntax highlighting to make the foreground color the same as the background. (I lack all knowledge in that area.) You'll get a line that appears blank. I don't believe you'll make the line itself disappear.

```
"The last character in the following two lines is a space
set fillchars=fold:\ 
set foldtext=\ 
"This is the default, so it's probably already set
set foldcolumn=0
```

EDIT 2024-03-30: I hadn't considered it, but all that's truly necessary is:

```
hi Folded ctermfg=(whatever your background color is)
```

This replaces the whole folded line with what looks like a blank line. Much easier to toggle this one setting than all of the others.

Comment: i know this, but this will only show folded rows as a blank row, not hide it. btw setting folded text color can be done via `:hi Folded ctermbg=#A0A0A0 guibg=#1f0000`, set colors properly it will be as same as a blank row.

Comment: @athos Turns out setting the foreground to the background is all that's necessary. Surely a blank line is nothing unusual in source code and would be closer to your goal than nothing at all.